# How to change a static IP NetworkManager Controlled from the shell?

Tags: networking, scientific-linux

I have a server (SL6.2) with IP configured from install, but now I need to change the IP address. The IP is controlled by the NwtworkManager:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 
DEVICE="eth1"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
HWADDR="34:40:B5:B8:1E:BA"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
```

I need to change the static IP, but it's a server and I have no x11 installed. How can I changed it in the NetworkManager configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This interface looks like it is configured to use DHCP. To make the configuration static, you change the file to look like:

```
BOOTPROTO="none"
IPADDR=<your.ip.addr.ess>
NETMASK=<your.sub.net.mask>
GATEWAY=<your.gate.way.ip>
```

Comment: thansk, It's a solution, But I'm interested in maintain the same ifcfg-ethX file, and change the networkmanager configuration ... or equivalent.